# Лазер упирается в пулю 2d unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

думаю и так понятно, что я ничего не понимаю в программировании и делаю все только по видосам. Столкнулся с проблемой, что мой динамический лазер(лцу) упирается в пулю и фиксируется на ней как на объекте. На лазере есть LineRender и сам лазер работает на RaycastHit2d. Пытался убрать с пули все коллайдеры и Rb, пытался мудрить с LayerMask, но без результатов. В ProjectSetings в юнити тоже работал с галочками что бы Raycast игнорил пулю, тоже мимо. Нужно что бы лазер игнорировал пулю. Помогите пожалуйста

Сам код лазера

[image: Фото]

```
RaycastHit2D raycastDetector;
public LineRenderer line;
public Transform tr;
public float largoDealLaser;
public float anchoDelCollider;

private void Update()
{
    line.SetPosition(0, (Vector2)tr.position + (Vector2)tr.right * (anchoDelCollider / 2));
    line.SetPosition(1, (Vector2)tr.position + (Vector2)tr.right * (largoDealLaser));

    raycastDetector = Physics2D.Raycast(tr.position + tr.right * anchoDelCollider / 2,
        tr.right, largoDealLaser - anchoDelCollider / 2);
    if (raycastDetector.collider != null)
        line.SetPosition(1, raycastDetector.point);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло убирание галочки "Queries Start In Colliders" в настройках проекта